# Save current date

Tags: java, android

I need some help in saving the current date. Is there any way to save the current date and time in which that activity is executed?

This is my code so far to declare the current date and time:

```
private String currentDateTimeString = 
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

Comment: What do you mean by save the current date in the activity? Do you mean to say that you want the `currentDateTimeString` to persist even after the activity has been closed?

Comment: Do you want to log the activity of an `Activity`?

Comment: I mean that when I re-enter the application in a toast it is shown the last date and time in which I have entered that particular activity @ChrisvinJem

Comment: Not really, I just want the date and time of the last time that I entered that activity @deHaar

Answer (score 1):

Best way to store time is in milliseconds format.

```
long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then while showing convert it to any format you want.

Light weight data can be stored in `SharedPreference`.

**EDIT:**

[Shared Preference Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Comment: Does this save the current time in milliseconds?

Comment: @User89 yes and you can convert it to your preferred format.

Comment: I've tried this but it isn't exactly what I was looking for, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the most recent date and time the activity is created to the device then I would recommend using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). Example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("DATE", currentDateTimeString);
editor.commit();
```

However, if you need to persistently store the date of every time the activity is created, then you should look into using a SQLite database or a persistent storage library such as Room